# In MFC APP, if I call "LoadLibraryA" from "InitInstance", it calls "InitInstance" again and again

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, loadlibrary

I have created an MFCApp using VS2008 wizard. Inside my application's "InitInstance()" I'm calling "LoadLibraryA()" method as I need to load a few dll files. But as soon as I call "LoadLibraryA()", it again calls "InitInstance()" of my application and hence it becomes a infinite recursion stuff. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
// CLoader_MFCApp initialization
BOOL CLoader_MFCApp::InitInstance()
{
  INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
  InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
  InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
  InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);
  CWinAppEx::InitInstance();
  SetRegistryKey(_T("MyApp"));

  HMODULE hm = LoadLibraryA("./abc/def.dll");
  // after above line InitInstance() gets called again

  // more code
  return FALSE;
}
```

Call Stack:

```
MyApp.exe!CLoader_MFCApp::InitInstance()    C++
CORE.dll!InternalDllMain(HINSTANCE__ *, unsigned long, void *)  C++
CORE.dll!__DllMainCRTStartup(void *, unsigned long, void *)     C
CORE.dll!_DllMainCRTStartup(void *, unsigned long, void *)  C
ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()     
ntdll.dll!_LdrpRunInitializeRoutines@4()    
ntdll.dll!_LdrpLoadDll@24()     
ntdll.dll!_LdrLoadDll@16()  
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExW@12()   
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryExA@12()   
kernel32.dll!_LoadLibraryA@4()  
MyApp.exe!CLoader_MFCApp::InitInstance()    C++
mfc90.dll!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ *, HINSTANCE__ *, char *, int)     C++
MyApp.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()   C
kernel32.dll!_BaseProcessStart@4()
```

"Def.dll" is any other dll and completely unrelated from MyApp. In this case, I'm trying to load another dll "CORE.dll"

All I can figure out is that I'm calling LoadLibrary before InitInstance routine is over. Is there any other (overridable) method which is called after InitInstance??? If so, I can try moving LoadLibrary calls to that method...

Comment: Use a debug build (also of the DLL, if possible), and post the call stack when you re-enter InitInstance after LoadLibrary.

Comment: What is ./abc/def.dll and what is it loading? Is it trying to load your library (circular dependency)?

Comment: What is the relation between "CLoader_MFCApp" and this "def.dll", any interdepency?

Comment: The code for DllMain in def.dll may be relevant. Chances are that code is doing something which should be moved into an explicit Init function in the DLL. (You're allowed to do very little in DllMain itself.)

Comment: But thats happening for EVERY dll i try to load :(

Comment: All I can figure out is that I'm calling LoadLibrary before InitInstance routine is over. Is there any other (overridable) method which is called after InitInstance??? If so, I can try moving LoadLibrary calls to that method...

Comment: You aren't allowed to call LoadLibrary from DLLMain. You'll simply have to stop doing this.

Comment: @DAVID its an EXE not a DLL and if I'm doing it wrong, atleast please suggest an alternative???

Comment: Are you building the DLLs with /D _AFXEXT in effect?

Comment: What is the type of Core.Dll? is it an MFC regular or extension dll?

Comment: Will it go into recursion if you load a Windows DLL, such as shell32.dll? If so, we can assume that something is fishy in your EXE. A product I'm working on is calling LoadLibrary() in InitInstance(), so I know it is possible to do it.

Comment: This sure looks like you're in a DLL.  This problem can happen if you call LoadLibrary from inside DllMain.  MFC InitInstance would be called from inside DllMain in an MFC DLL, or WinMain in an MFC Windows app.  But you say clearly, and your call stack shows clearly, that this is an EXE.  I can't see why this would happen.  WinMain is a perfectly OK place to call LoadLibrary.  Maybe there's memory corruption and the loader or call stack or something is confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing something wrong.
You are in mfc90.dll's DllMain and it is not safe to call LoadLibrary from DllMain, says so right here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than a true solution (i.e. I don't know the rules for LoadLibrary in MFC, as I've never read anything to say you can't, nor do I happen to use this technique in our MFC code).

However, Generally speaking, if windows coughs up a hairball due to order of operations, I just move the calls out to another message handler.  You can even *post* a thread message to your application, and write a handler for that message.

Something like:

```
// in InitInstance - post a message to our main thread to handle after init instance...
PostMessage(NULL, WM_PostInit);

// in your message table
ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_PostInit, OnPostInit)

// in your app
void MyApp::OnPostInit(WPARAM,LPARAM) // both args unused
{
  // try load library now...!
}
```

NOTE: The above is "brain code" - untested.  Details undoubtedly need to be massaged for full compilability.

References:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same `issue`, `caused by` the `Configuration type` being incorrectly set to `exe` not `dll` for the `dll` to be loaded.

Fix: `Project -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type = Dynamic Library (.dll)` (was incorrectly set to Application (.exe))